# htaccess: Rewrite collision - simple question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This row will certainly cause a little collision as it will try to rewrite the goal itself:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ page.php?q=$1 [L,NC]
```

Now, how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a condition that the matched string is not the same as the destination:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=page.php
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ page.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Here the `!=` in `RewriteCond` indicates a negated lexicographic comparison instead of the implied regular expression comparison.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seem to work - I get a 404. Does it matter where the condition is placed? I mean, should it be placed on the line above the rule, or before all the rules in the file, or...?
I also tried with Lekensteyn's solution without success.

Comment: @Ivarska: A `RewriteCond` does only belong to the first following `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Learning something new every day. :-) There's where I placed it first. So what could be the problem?

Comment: @Ivarska: Oh, I just saw that you tagged it with .htaccess. If you’re using it in an .htaccess file, you need to remove the path prefix from the pattern; in your case probably the leading `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a conditional Rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^page.php?
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ page.php?q=$1 [L,NC]
```